# Unable to click on EditText field which is not in focus

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have a situation like I am automating a native app using Appium(1.3.7) and Selenium webdriver (2.44) in that I want to enter the Date of birth field, when I am clicking on Date of birth field, it will pop up a window to enter the date of birth details, that window is not in focus and appium is failing to enter the details on the window as it is not able to recognize here I am not able to attach the screenshot.

Please help me how to get in to focus and enter the Date of birth details..
Using Google I tried a lot of methods like:

### Method : 1

```
List<WebElement> Listed= dr.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.EditText");

   for(int i=0; i <=Listed.size()-1;i++){
   System.out.println("EditText Number="+i);
   Listed.get(i).sendKeys("10");
```

### Method : 2

```
    WebElement Touch1= dr.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.EditText']"));
//    
       TouchAction action = new TouchAction(dr);
       action.press(168,440);
       action.waitAction(300);
       action.perform();
```

### Method : 3

```
dr.tap(168,440,405,591);
```

### Method : 4

```
WebElement DOBsample = dr.findElementByXPath("//*[text()[contains(.,'20')]]");
DOBsample.click();
```

### Method : 5

```
dr.sendKeyEvent(66);
```

Comment: any one respond please as it is important for me

Comment: have you tried the full xpath? like, get the whole hirearchy?

Comment: Is that window with pickers (android 4.4-), or regular calendar (android 5.0+) ?

Answer (score 0):

For pickers, you must use swiping over them. I´m using Scala, but logic is obvious:

```
def setYear(year: Int): Unit = {
require(year >= 1915 || year <= 2015)
val picker = drvr.findElementById("cz.app.yearPicker")
while (picker.getText != year.toString) {
  if (picker.getText.toInt > year) {
     swipePickerDown(picker)
     } else { swipePickerUp(picker) }
  }
}

def swipePickerUp(picker: AndroidElement): Unit = {
  picker.swipe(SwipeElementDirection.UP, 400)
}

def swipePickerDown(picker: AndroidElement): Unit = {
  picker.swipe(SwipeElementDirection.DOWN, 400)
}
```